# Dynamic (real) context menu for jtable row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

I want different menu items in the context menu depending on the row I clicked in the JTable

most of examples do not really show a context menu (supposed to be populated depending on the context - the selected row)

I tried this:

```
    popupMenu = new JPopupMenu(){
         @Override
        public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {
            int rowAtPoint = table.rowAtPoint(SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(x, y), table));
                FilesManager.this.generateTablePopupMenu(rowAtPoint);
            super.show(invoker, x, y);
        }
    };
```

where generateTablePopupMenu is adding/removing menuitems depending on the row data

but it does not work, the index (rowAtPoint) does not return correct values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JPopupMenu#show(int, int) (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show-java.awt.Component-int-int-)

> **public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y)**
>
> Displays the popup menu **at the position x,y in the coordinate space of the component invoker**.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - invoker - the component in whose space the popup menu is to appear
> - x - the x coordinate in invoker's coordinate space at which the popup menu is to be displayed
> - y - the y coordinate in invoker's coordinate space at which the popup menu is to be displayed

Therefore, it is not necessary to convert the coordinates using the `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)` method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JTablePopupMenuTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(5, 3));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu() {
      @Override
      public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {
        //int rowAtPoint = table.rowAtPoint(
        //    SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(x, y), table));
        //FilesManager.this.generateTablePopupMenu(rowAtPoint);
        int rowAtPoint = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(x, y));
        System.out.println(rowAtPoint);
        super.show(invoker, x, y);
      }
    };
    table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JTablePopupMenuTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.